# python DataFrame: get 'set' from DataFrame elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I get 'set' data from DataFrame elements?

For example, if I have a data as

```
df = DataFrame([['a','b','z'], ['a', 'c'], ['d']])
```

I would like to get

```
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z'}
```

(type: set)

If I use for sentence, I can code it. However, if there is another way to calculate with pandas, I would like to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataFrame.stack(dropna=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) per default drops all NaNs

```
In [56]: df.stack().tolist()
Out[56]: ['a', 'b', 'z', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

or as a set:

```
In [57]: set(df.stack().tolist())
Out[57]: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = set(df.values.ravel())
>>> s
{None, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z'}
```

Technically, the value `None` should be in the result.  You could always remove it with `s.remove(None)` if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A=[]
[A.extend(item)for item in df.values.tolist() ]
A = list(set([i for i in A if i is not None]))


A
Out[1224]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']
```